# Keep value or text of Option Select from Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've 8 Empty box where on click open a Modal view passing the ID of the box. Inside the Modal there is a Select Option when on click send the information to the DB with AJAX. All the box use the same code but the first 5 are working and the others 3 are sending "Empty" value for the selected option.

That's my code to launch the Modal: (this is working)

```
function popupEmptyCat(id) {
   $('#category'+id).modal('show');
}
```

When the modal is open show the select option:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
     <select id="selectcat" name="category" class="form-control">
            <option value="Empty">Empty</option>
            <?php foreach ($category as $key => $value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value['category']; ?>">
              <?php echo $value['category']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <button onclick="setCategory(5);" class="btn btn-block btn-white">Set</button>
</div>
```

And on click to the button SET launch the setCategory script:

```
function setCategory(id) {
   var user_id = <?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>;
   var position = "category"+id;
   var category = $('#selectcat :selected').text();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>social/chg_set_position/"+category+"/"+position+"/"+user_id,
                data:{},  
                success: function(){ location.reload(); }
        });
}
```

Comment: why r u refreshing the page?? you can populate all the fields in ajax success() only.

Comment: The refresh could be a problem?

Comment: not actually, but, it ll be easy to do it without refresh.

Comment: Sure but at the moment i've write this just to refresh the page and see the category changed in a box so i don't have to refresh the page every time.
The problem in this function is how i keep the var category, infact duplicating the function (naming it setAnotherCategory() ) and changing the id of the select option is working on all the others 3 box.

Comment: in ajax success, will you get to no, what r the values for all 8 boxes??

Comment: id contain numbers from 1 till 8, the $value['category']; contain random names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91734/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-mds).